# How to get my MODEL JB6612 Long Distance Wifi Antenna to run on ubuntu 20.04 ? I have no driver or software for it anymore

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-recommendation

I used it successfully when I was running Windows. I now changed over to Ubuntu 20.04 when I got a new computer. I no longer have the CD for the Ideaworks indoor/outdoor long distance WIFI antenna. Powered by USB.

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 used by mouse Wireless Desktop 900
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 19ff:0239 Dynex 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0ac8:c444 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: An antenna wouldn't require drivers but this product has a very misleading advertising. It's actually a standard USB WiFi device plus a long range antenna. **People looking for a better antenna with a SMA connector SHOULDN'T by this product**. That said, and because it is a standard WiFi dongle, please run `lsusb` in terminal with it connected, of course, then edit your question with the relevant line of the result that identifies the WiFi chipset.

Comment: I have had very little experience with Ubuntu but I think this is what you suggested ln your answer ChanganAuto.

Comment: Not an answer, I'm asking for information in order to help you. Is there something you don't understand in run the `lsusb` command and post here the line that identifies the WiFi device?

Comment: I added more info that I think is what you suggested @ChanganAuto

Comment: Indeed and I just edited it out keeping only what's relevant. Now, the thing is it should just work. The chipset is natively supported since many years ago. What is the problem exactly? Isn't it recognized? Can't "see" networks? Or can but doesn't connect (in which case what happens exactly, asks for the password over and over? Error messages?) Or seems to be connected but doesn't open webpages? Or...?

Comment: when using it on windows pc it had software that flashed when I started the pc. This doesn't so I don't know how to see if it is running or not but my signal strength doesn't seem to improve with or without it plugged in  to Linux. I know little about ubuntu and terminal so thanks for bearing with me. I ran the following with antenna plugged in and unplugged and got same result tail -f /var/log/messages
tail: cannot open '/var/log/messages' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
I also tried lshw -C network  but result was to big to send you@ChanganAuto

Answer (score 0):

@Bill - I also have this model but I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, so I don't know if your GUI will be different from mine. When I go to my Wi-Fi Settings window, on the top brown bar I have 2 buttons: one for my internal wireless card, and another one right next to it labelled "802.11 n WLAN". If you click that button, and make sure that the slider next to it is in the orange "ON" position, you should be in business...no extra drivers needed!